# How to preview Collections for my Open Graph Test User?

Tags: collections, facebook-opengraph

I'm in the process of preparing an Open Graph Collection for submission to Facebook for approval.

The approval process requires publishing 8 actions to my Open Graph Test User, and I would like to preview this user's collection before hitting submit to ensure everything is good.

The docs indicate that app collections can be viewed by going to http://facebook.com/me/app_[namespace].

When I am logged in with my personal FB account, I can navigate to the above URL, using either the app's namespace or APP_ID, no problems.

But when I switch to the Test User and enter this URL, I seem to go through two or three redirects (the address bar cycles through URLs), before being returned to the Test User's timeline.

How can I view the Open Graph Test User's collection for my app?

Comment: I figured out that it's not a test user issue. It's a role issue. Even real facebook accounts with role "Tester" can't see the collection. Only app administrators and developer can see it. Hopefully they'll fix this issue soon.